# Where is the python core file located

Tags: python, printing, ide

As we know in Python 3.0 turned print in the function form so I want to know where is the file with source of print function is located

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to ask about builtin function.
The python interpreter has predefined functions that are always ready for use.

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/bltinmodule.c